# How do all the web frameworks handle schema updates/migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django, data-migration, web-frameworks

I'm curious as to how all the web frameworks handle schema updates and migration - I know Django does not have built-in support but has `django-south`.

Do any frameworks have similar functionality natively built-in? If so what are they and how intuitive are they to use?

EDIT: Well, not **all** but the most common ones, eg:

- Rails
- Pyramid/Pylons
- Sinatra
- ASP.NET
- Catalyst
- Zend

Comment: Am I blind or do I not see the community wiki checkbox?

Comment: +1 I am very curious about this as well. `django-south` works well but perhaps there's something better that I'm unaware of.

Answer (score 0):

Asp.net does not have a natively built-in equivalent to rails migrations. But it does have some decent 3rd party solutions for migrations. They are part of 3rd party solutions like [Migrator.net](http://code.google.com/p/migratordotnet) and [Subsonic](http://subsonicproject.com)

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033/database-migration-library-for-net) for more info

Comment: ASP.NET does not have ... *any built-in equivalent of an ORM or non-bare-bones data-access layer* ... ;-)

Comment: @pst sorry i don't get what you're saying. asp.net has linq to sql and entity framework. but that's not what this question is about. sorry, i'm confused here.

Answer (score 0):

[web2py](http://www.web2py.com) (a full-stack Python web framework) includes built-in automatic [migrations](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/06#Migrations) functionality. The framework as a whole is [very easy to learn and use](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/00), as is the migrations functionality, which you simply turn on or off (per table or globally). Migrations are handled by the web2py [DAL](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/06) (database abstraction layer), which incidentally can be used [stand-alone](http://web2py.com/AlterEgo/default/show/272) outside the web2py framework as well.

If you have any questions, I recommend asking the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/web2py), which is very friendly and responsive.